# Google Dataflow - Failed to import custom python modules

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Apache beam pipeline implements custom Transforms and ParDo's python modules which further imports other modules written by me. On Local runner this works fine as all the available files are available in the same path. In case of Dataflow runner, pipeline fails with module import error.

How do I make custom modules available to all the dataflow workers? Please advise.

Below is an example:

```
ImportError: No module named DataAggregation

    at find_class (/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py:1130)
    at find_class (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py:423)
    at load_global (/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py:1096)
    at load (/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py:864)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py:266)
    at loads (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py:277)
    at loads (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py:232)
    at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.PGBKCVOperation.__init__ (operations.py:508)
    at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.create_pgbk_op (operations.py:452)
    at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.create_operation (operations.py:613)
    at create_operation (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py:104)
    at execute (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py:130)
    at do_work (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py:642)
```

Answer (score 11):

The issue is probably that you haven't grouped your files as a package. The Beam documentation has [a section](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies) on it.

> ### Multiple File Dependencies
>
> Often, your pipeline code spans multiple files. To run your project remotely, you must group these files as a Python package and specify the package when you run your pipeline. When the remote workers start, they will install your package. To group your files as a Python package and make it available remotely, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Create a [setup.py](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) file for your project. The following is a very basic `setup.py` file.
>
>    ```
>    setuptools.setup(
>        name='PACKAGE-NAME'
>        version='PACKAGE-VERSION',
>        install_requires=[],
>        packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
>    )
>    ```
> 2. Structure your project so that the root directory contains the `setup.py` file, the main workflow file, and a directory with the rest of the files.
>
>    ```
>    root_dir/
>        setup.py
>        main.py
>        other_files_dir/
>    ```
>
> See [Juliaset](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset) for an example that follows this required project structure.
>
> 3. Run your pipeline with the following command-line option:
>
>    ```
>    --setup_file /path/to/setup.py
>    ```
>
> *Note:* If you created a requirements.txt file and your project spans multiple files, you can get rid of the requirements.txt file and instead, add all packages contained in requirements.txt to the install_requires field of the setup call (in step 1).

Comment: That makes a lot sense. I updated the answer with a quote of the relevant section since there's not much to condense from the section's instructions.

Comment: Worth noting is that the `setup.py` file is in the same directory where you run your final `python` command, then you must preppend `./` to it:   `--setup_file ./setup.py`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and unfortunately, the docs are not as verbose as they need to be.
So, the problem as it turns out is that both the `root_dir` and the `other_files_dir` must contain an `__init__.py` file. When a directory contains an `__init__.py` file (even if it's empty) python will treat that directory as a package, which in this instance is what we want. So, your final folder structure should look something like this:

```
root_dir/
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    main.py
    other_files_dir/
        __init__.py
        module_1.py
        module_2.py
```

And what you'll find is that python will build an `.egg-info` folder that describes your package including all pip dependencies. It will also contain the `top_level.txt` file which contains the name of the directory that holds the modules (i.e `other_files_dir`)

Then you would simply call the modules in `main.py` as below

```py
from other_files_dir import module_1
```