# Google Dataflow: Import custom Python module

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I try to run a Apache Beam pipeline (Python) within Google Cloud Dataflow, triggered by a DAG in Google Cloud Coomposer.

The structure of my dags folder in the respective GCS bucket is as follows:

```
/dags/
  dataflow.py <- DAG
  dataflow/
    pipeline.py <- pipeline
    setup.py
    my_modules/
      __init__.py
      commons.py <- the module I want to import in the pipeline
```

The setup.py is very basic, but according to the Apache Beam docs and answers on SO:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(setuptools.find_packages())
```

In the DAG file (dataflow.py) I set the `setup_file` option and pass it to Dataflow:

```
default_dag_args = {
    ... ,
    'dataflow_default_options': {
        ... ,
        'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
        'setup_file': os.path.join(configuration.get('core', 'dags_folder'), 'dataflow', 'setup.py')
    }
}
```

Within the pipeline file (pipeline.py) I try to use

```
from my_modules import commons
```

but this fails. The log in Google Cloud Composer (Apache Airflow) says:

```
gcp_dataflow_hook.py:132} WARNING - b'  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/dataflow/dataflow.py", line 11\n    from my_modules import commons\n           ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax'
```

The basic idea behind the setup.py file is documented [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies)

Also, there are similar questions on SO which helped me:

[Google Dataflow - Failed to import custom python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262031/google-dataflow-failed-to-import-custom-python-modules)

[Dataflow/apache beam: manage custom module dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763406/dataflow-apache-beam-manage-custom-module-dependencies)

I'm actually wondering why my pipelines fails with a `Syntax Error` and not a `module not found` kind of error...

Comment: It looks like syntax issue. have you checked the spaces correctly since it is python ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce your issue and then try to solve it, so I created the same folder structure you already have:

```
/dags/
  dataflow.py
  dataflow/
     pipeline.py -> pipeline
     setup.py
     my_modules/
        __init__.py
        common.py
```

Therefore, to make it work, the change I made is to copy these folders to a place where the instance is running the code is able to find it, for example in the `/tmp/` folder of the instance.

So, my DAG would be something like this:

1 - Fist of all I declare my arguments:

```
default_args = {
   'start_date': datetime(xxxx, x, x),
   'retries': 1,
   'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
   'dataflow_default_options': {
       'project': '<project>',
       'region': '<region>',
       'stagingLocation': 'gs://<bucket>/stage',
       'tempLocation': 'gs://<bucket>/temp',
       'setup_file': <setup.py>,
       'runner': 'DataflowRunner'
   }
}
```

2- After this, I created the DAG and before running the Dataflow task, I copied the whole folder directory, above created, into the `/tmp/` folder of the instance `Task t1`, and after this, I run the pipeline from the /tmp/ directory `Task t2`:

```
with DAG(
    'composer_df',
     default_args=default_args,
     description='datflow dag',
     schedule_interval="xxxx") as dag:

     def copy_dependencies():
          process = subprocess.Popen(['gsutil','cp', '-r' ,'gs://<bucket>/dags/*', 
          '/tmp/'])
          process.communicate()


     t1 = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='copy_dependencies',
        python_callable=copy_dependencies,
        provide_context=False
     )


     t2 = DataFlowPythonOperator(task_id="composer_dataflow", 
          py_file='/tmp/dataflow/pipeline.py', job_name='job_composer')

     t1 >> t2
```

That's how I created the DAG file `dataflow.py`, and then, in the `pipeline.py` the package to import would be like:

```
from my_modules import commons
```

It should work fine, since the folder directory is understandable for the VM.